# GORM addTo methods not found in Spock test

Tags: grails-orm, spring-boot

I am using Gorm standalone with spring-boot.

I have a domain class, annotated with @Entity, which has several children collections.

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes="id")
class Order {
  String hash

  static hasMany = [lines:OrderLine]

  static mapping = {
    hash column: 'hash', index: 'hash_index'
    inputs lazy: false
  }

}
```

Here is one of the child classes:

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(includes="id")
class OrderLine {
  int lineNo
  double amount

  static belongsTo = [transaction: Transaction]

  static constraints = {
    lineNo validator: {val -> val>=0}
    amount validator: {val -> val>=0.0}
  }

}
```

In a Spock test, after creating an Order, I cannot use the addToLines method. It complains that there is no signature of method addToLines.

If I manually set the lines collection to an ArrayList, I can then manually add a line, which is later persisted. If I don't manually initialize the lines collection, attempts to simply add fail.

So when in GORM do these collections get created and the addTo methods added to the class?

Dependencies in my gradle.build include:

```
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter",
"org.grails:gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot:1.0.0.RELEASE",
```

Comment: A similar Grails 2.4 HibernateTestMixin bug has been reported. See https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11579 .

Comment: I think this commit will fix the bug https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/commit/b6801326

Comment: Yet another fix: https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/commit/eda5d6b1